# Add Get Set DatagridViewTextBoxCell

Tags: c#, datagridview

I try to add a `get; set;` property into my DataGridViewTextBoxCell but it's not working

For that I create my public class :

```
public class MyData : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
    {
        public string Url { get; set; }
    }
```

And in my main code

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
MyData CustomCell = (MyData)dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0];
CustomCell.Url = "";
```

During code execution I have the error on the line 
`MyData CustomCell = (MyData)dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0];`

> System.InvalidCastException : 'Unable to cast Object type System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxCell' into type .MyData'.'

Do you have a clue to add my custom property in datagridview cell ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to create a `Column` class and set the `CellTemplate` property to a new instance of the `Cell` class:

```cs
public class MyDataGridViewTextBoxColumn : DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
{
    public MyDataGridViewTextBoxColumn() =>
        CellTemplate = new MyDataGridViewTextBoxCell();
}
```

And your `Cell` class should be like:

```cs
public class MyDataGridViewTextBoxCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{
    public MyDataGridViewTextBoxCell() { }

    public string Url { get; set; }

    //Don't forget to clone your new properties.
    public override object Clone()
    {
        var c = base.Clone();
        ((MyDataGridViewTextBoxCell)c).Url = Url;
        return c;
    }
}
```

Now you can add the new `Column` type by the designer:

[image: Custom DGV Column]

Or through the code:

```cs
var myNewTBC = new MyDataGridViewTextBoxColumn
{
    HeaderText = "My Custom TB",
};
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(myNewTBC);
```

Assuming that the custom text box column is the first column in the DGV, then you can get a `Cell` as follows:

```cs
var myTB = (MyDataGridViewTextBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0];
myTB.Url = "...";
```